# Redirection if language of browser is not russian

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, hyperlink, uri

This is extended my last question. I wrote a function on JS

```
const uri = window.location;
const lang = window.navigator.language;
if( uri.href.indexOf('lang') < 0) {
    if (lang != 'ru-RU'){
        const re = "https://www.site/";
        const url = window.location.href;
        const newstr = url.replace(re, 'https://www.site/en/');
        window.location.href = newstr;
    }
}
```

But when I'm entering from english browser, it's just keeping redirecting and in few seconds link starts looking like this: `https://www.site/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/`. Can url be replaced only one time?

Comment: you do not find `'lang'` in the uri and the `lang` is not `ru-RU`, therefore you continously redirect.

Comment: if I enter site from russian browser `ru-RU`, Nothing will happen, because function will be executed only when `lang != ru-RU`.

Comment: Yes, but if you are english user you are not a russian user therefore you continously redirect.

Comment: @luk2302 How can I fix that? I didn't get that: `you do not find 'lang' in the uri and the lang is not ru-RU`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

const uri = window.location;
const lang = window.navigator.language;
if( uri.href.indexOf('lang') < 0) {
    if (lang != 'ru-RU'){
eng = window.location.href.includes('https://www.fashiondance.in.ua/en/');
console.log(eng);
if (eng == false){
const re = "https://www.fashiondance.in.ua/";
const url = window.location.href;
const newstr = url.replace(re, 'https://www.fashiondance.in.ua/en/');
window.location.href = newstr;
}
}
}
</script>
```